# Count of subarray

Tags: arrays, algorithm, count, subset, sub-array

The problem is a variant of subarray counting. Given an array of numbers, let's say, `1,2,2,3,2,1,2,2,2,2` I look for subarrays and count the frequency of each. I start with looking from some `K` length subarrays (example K = 3).

Count of subarray `1,2,2` is `C1:2`.

Count of subarray `2,2,3` is `1`.

Count of subarray `2,3,2` is `1`.

and so on.

Now, I look for subarrays of length 2.
Count of subarray `1,2` is `C2: 2`. But (1,2) is a subset of the subarray `1,2,2`. So, I calculate its count by subtracting `C1` from `C2` which gives count of `1,2` as 0. Similarly, count of `2,2` is `1`.
My problem is in handling cases where more than one parent subset exists. I don't consider the sub-arrays in my result set whose frequency comes out to be 1. Example:
`1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,2,3`

Here, Count of `1,2,3` is `2`.

Count of `2,3,1` is `2`.

Now, when I look for count of `2,3`, it should be 1 as all the greater length parents have covered the occurrences. How shall I handle these cases?

The approach I thought was to mark all the pattern occurrences of the parent. In the above case, mark all the occurrences of `1,2,3` and `2,3,1`. Array looks like this:

`1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,2,3`

`X,X,X,X,X,X,X,2,2,3`

where X denotes the marked position. Now, frequency of `2,3` we see is 1 as per the positions which are unmarked. So, basically, I mark all the pattern occurrences I find at the current step. For the next step, I start looking for patterns from the unmarked locations only to get the correct count.

I am dealing with the large data on which this seems a bit not-so-good thing to do. Also, I'm not sure if it's correct or not. Any other approaches or ideas can be of big help?

Comment: It isn't quite clear what exactly are you calculating - why are you substracting C1 from C2? Why in the second example the count for `2,3` should be 1?

Comment: In the second example if you see, count of 2,3 is 3. But 2 occurrences have already come in subarrays of length 3"1,2,3". (1,2,3),(1,2,3),1,2,2,2,3. Hence, the last 2,3, only comes in the count.

Comment: But 2,3 is also a subarray of 2,3,1 and 2,2,3. Why are you interested in 1,2,3 only?

Comment: @algrid Edited. Count of (2,3) should be 1 as all the bigger length parents, (1,2,3) and (2,3,1) have covered the occurrences. I don't consider the subarray whose count is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) for given array.

To **count all repeating subarrays with given lengt**h - walk through this suffix array, comparing neighbor suffixes by needed prefix length.
For your first example

```
source array 
1,2,2,3,2,1,2,2,2,2
suffix array is 
5,0,9,4,8,7,6,1,2,3:

1,2,2,2,2              (5)
1,2,2,3,2,1,2,2,2,2    (0)
2                      (9)
2,1,2,2,2,2            (4) 
2,2                    (8)
2,2,2                  (7)
2,2,2,2                (6)
2,2,3,2,1,2,2,2,2      (1)
2,3,2,1,2,2,2,2        (2)
3,2,1,2,2,2,2          (3)
```

With length 2 we can count two subarrays `1,2` and four subarrays `2,2`

If you want to **count any given subarray** - for example, all suffixes beginning with `(1,2)`, just use binary search to get the first and the last indexes (like `std:upperbound` and `std:lowerbound` operations in C++ STL).
For the same example indexes of the first and last occurrences of `(1,2)` **in suffix array** are 0 and 1, so count is `last-first+1=2`

Comment: If I try building the suffix array for the first example where array is 1,2,2,3,2,1,2,2,2,2, then suffix array would be 5,0,9,8,7,6,4,2,1,3. How are you now counting the occurrences of any subarray? Example,, if I  want to count for 1,2. You look for all suffixes beginning with (1,2)? An example will really help.

Comment: I've added  more explanations.